# jquery iterate over inner-child element from child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have the next html:

```
<div id="segmenter">
    <div id="variable" name="Zone">
        <h3>Zona</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><input id="category" type="checkbox" value="Center">Center</li>
            <li><input id="category" type="checkbox" value="East">East</li>
            <li><input id="category" type="checkbox" value="South">South</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="variable" name="Type of">
        <h3>Tipo de Restaurante</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><input id="category" type="checkbox" value="Freestander">Freestander</li>
            <li><input id="category" type="checkbox" value="Instore">Instore</li>
            <li><input id="category" type="checkbox" value="Mall">Mall</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to iterate firstly over all div child of segmenter with id "variable", then iterate over all input with id "category" of each child "variable".

Using Chrome Dev tools:

With:

```
$("#segmenter > #variable")
```

I get every div variable: `[<div id=​"variable" name=​"Zona">​…​</div>​, <div id=​"variable" name=​"Tipo de Restaurante">​…​</div>​]`

Now from here everything that I tried don't work, for example:

```
$("#segmenter > #variable").find("#category");
```

I only get 4 input "category": `[<input id=​"category" type=​"checkbox" value=​"Centro">​, <input id=​"category" type=​"checkbox" value=​"Freestander">​, <input id=​"category" type=​"checkbox" value=​"Instore">​, <input id=​"category" type=​"checkbox" value=​"Mall">​]`

I don't know why, what I need is iterate something like:

```
var oVariables = $("#segmenter > #variable");
$.each(oVariables, function(){
    var oCategory = $(this).find("#category").text();//in the first call for div-name="zone", only have the first input-value"center"
    //Iterate Again
        //get checked values, etc
});
```

Many Thanks.

Comment: An `id` is unique. Use `classes` instead, for a collection.

Comment: What do you want to do when you iterate over them? Sorry, that part is still unclear.

Comment: @nickcoxdotme Get all checked values and pass them to an Action of some Controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ID should always be unique**..

use class  instead of ids in your case. like:

```
<div id="variable" name="Zone">
    _^_ here
<div class="variable" name="Zone"> //do this for all ids
```

and your selector

```
$("#segmenter > .variable").find(".category");
```

Answer (score 1):

An id is unique. Use classes instead, for a collection. Change all IDs to Classes and then iterate as such:

```
$.each($('div.variable'), function(elem){
    $.each($(elem).find('input.category'), function(childElem){
        //Do something with childElem here
    })
});
```

Comment: `childElem` Is index of element ...for access element you must do like `$.each($(elem).find('input.category'), function(childElem,Element){
        //Do something with childElem here
    })`

Answer (score 1):

Do not use ID's !!! Id's are unique!!! try using class instead

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem.I need access new child tag.

My Way:

```
var list_group_items = $("a.list-group-item");
    $.each(list_group_items,function(index,value){
        $(list_group_items[index]).hover(function(){
            $.each($(list_group_items[index]).find('small'), function(childElem,Element){
                console.log(Element);
                TweenLite.to(Element, 2, {"visibility":"visible"});
            });

        },function(){
            $.each($(list_group_items[index]).find('small'), function(childElem,Element){
                //Do something with childElem here
                TweenLite.to(Element, 2, {"visibility":""});
            });

        });
    });
```

Note1: on `$.each` function have two argument, first one is *index* of iterate and second is *element*.

Note2:I using TeenMax Library for animation.